# Evaluate limit of integration $\lim_{x \to \infty} (\int_0^x e^{t^2} dt)^2/\int_0^x e^{2t^2} dt$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to evaluate $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac {\bigg(\displaystyle\int_{0}^x e^{t^2} dt \bigg)^2} {\displaystyle\int_{0}^x e^{2t^2} dt} =\ ?$$ Can we apply  L'Hospital's rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:
 $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac {\bigg(\displaystyle\int_{0}^x e^{t^2} dt \bigg)^2} {\displaystyle\int_{0}^x e^{2t^2} dt} =\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac {2e^{x^2}\displaystyle\int_{0}^x e^{t^2} dt } { e^{2x^2} }=\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac {2\displaystyle\int_{0}^x e^{t^2} dt } { e^{x^2} }=\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac {2\displaystyle e^{x^2} } { 2xe^{x^2} }=0\ .$$