# How to solve this limit? $ \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{(\int^x_0e^{x^2}dx)^2}{\int_0^xe^{2x^2}dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

There's  a limit which confuses me:

$$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac{(\int^x_0e^{x^2}dx)^2}{\int_0^xe^{2x^2}dx}$$

Is it possible to use L'Hôpital's rule here?

Comment: There seems to be rather confused notation in your post. But I guess you wanted to ask basically the same question as here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305577/what-is-the-result-for-this-limit-its-a-bit-complex
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231158/compute-lim-x-rightarrow-infty-frac-intx-0-ey2-dy2-intx-0
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837300/evaluate-limit-of-integration\

Comment: Based on the accepted answer it seems that you wanted to ask about the same problem as the other questions - so I can think these questions can be considered duplicates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible, since numerator and denominator are differentiable and go to $\infty$. Use also Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{(\int^x_0e^{t^2}dt)^2}{\int_0^xe^{2t^2}dt}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2e^{x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt}{e^{2x^2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}2\frac{\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt}{e^{x^2}}=2\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{x^2}}{2xe^{x^2}}=0$$

Comment: All too easy. (+1)

Comment: You have $x$ in too many places

Answer (score 1):

An asymptotic way:

Let $\displaystyle F:x\mapsto \int_0^x e^{t^2} dt$.

Note that $$\frac{(\int^x_0e^{t^2}dt)^2}{\int_0^xe^{2t^2}dt} = \sqrt 2\frac{(F(x))^2}{F(\sqrt 2 x)}$$

Moreover, $$\begin{align}
F(x)&=\int_0^1 e^{t^2} dt + \int_1^x \frac{1}{2t}\cdot 2te^{t^2}dt \\
&= \int_0^1 e^{t^2} dt + \frac{e^{x^2}}{2x}-\frac e2  +\frac 12 \int_1^x \frac{e^{t^2}}{t^2}dt
\end{align}$$
The same trick performed on $\displaystyle \int_1^x \frac{e^{t^2}}{t^2}dt$ yields
$$\begin{align}
F(x)&= \int_0^1 e^{t^2} dt + \frac{e^{x^2}}{2x}-\frac e2  + \frac{e^{x^2}}{4x^3} - \frac e4 + \frac 34 \int_1^x \frac{e^{t^2}}{t^4}dt
\end{align}$$

Note that for large enough $x$, $\displaystyle \int_1^x \frac{e^{t^2}}{t^4}dt\leq (x-1)\frac{e^{x^2}}{x^4}\leq \frac{e^{x^2}}{x^3}$.

Therefore, $$F(x)=\frac{e^{x^2}}{2x} + \frac{e^{x^2}}{4x^3} + O\left(\frac{e^{x^2}}{x^3}\right)$$

For the purpose of the question, it is enough to write $$F(x)=\frac{e^{x^2}}{2x} + o\left(\frac{e^{x^2}}{2x}\right)$$

which is the same as $\displaystyle F(x)\sim \frac{e^{x^2}}{2x}$. This implies $\displaystyle F(\sqrt 2 x)\sim \frac{e^{2x^2}}{2\sqrt 2x}$

Therefore, $$\frac{(\int^x_0e^{t^2}dt)^2}{\int_0^xe^{2t^2}dt} = \sqrt 2\frac{(F(x))^2}{F(\sqrt 2 x)}\sim \frac 1x\xrightarrow[x\to \infty]{}0$$