# What is the result for this limit $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(\int _0^xe^{t^2}dt\:\right)^2}{\int _0^xe^{2t^2}dt\:}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

what is the result for this limit?  $$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(\int _0^xe^{t^2}dt\:\right)^2}{\int _0^xe^{2t^2}dt\:}\right)$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: This seems to be a frequent question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182172/how-to-solve-the-limit-lim-x-to-infty-dfrac-intx-0ex2dx2-in
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231158/compute-lim-x-rightarrow-infty-frac-intx-0-ey2-dy2-intx-0
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837300/evaluate-limit-of-integration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate limit of integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837300/evaluate-limit-of-integration)

Comment: I see, im new here so I didn't find out there were similar questions, I began with maths degree few time ago, and I was asked to solve this limit for homework, and I was a bit dumb for trying to solve the integrals first, until here I realized how easy it was to solve just by using l'hopital, way much easier than it looked at first ! Thanks lots for the advice!!

Comment: If it helps you in the future, I was able to find the duplicates using [this search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%20_0%5Exe%5E%7B2t%5E2%7Ddt%24&p=1) in Approach0. (As you can see, 4 users chosen other closure reason, not duplicate. In the banner you have a link which might be worth reading: [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
f(x)=\int_0^x e^{t^2}\,dt
\qquad
g(x)=\int_0^x e^{2t^2}\,dt
$$
Then
$$
f'(x)=e^{x^2}
\qquad
g'(x)=e^{2x^2}
$$
Also, the derivative of $h(x)=(f(x))^2$ is $h'(x)=2f'(x)f(x)$.

Now you can apply l'Hôpital (twice, remember to simplify after the first step).

Comment: Thanks for the help!! its quite useful cause im starting the maths degree and its a different method or approach than the one used in college, so Im beginning to get used to it !